# Where can I get a good set of IDE icons?

Tags: icons

I'm developing a small IDE, and I'm wondering where I can find a set of IDE icons. A few google searches didn't turn anything up that was too useful. I suppose that's probably because an 'ide icon set' wouldn't get very many purchases (compared to more generic icons).

In any case, does anyone know where I can get some such icons? Certain icons such as save, load, etc I can find myself. I'm looking for more debugging-related icons.

Icons I'm interested in include:

- start debug
- step over, step into, etc
- run/debug
- view dissassembly
- etc.

I'd like some larger ones for the main toolbar, plus some mini's for to sit beside important actions in the dropdown menus.

I will very likely not be profiting from my humble IDE, but in the case that I 'go commercial', I'd like the icons' license(s) to not limit me that way. I have no problem with attribution in the about menu and in the code, however.

Finally, commercial icons are not at all off-limits if they're reasonably cheap, but I'd prefer free ones :)

Thanks!

---

### Update: 100 rep bounty

[Here](http://tango.freedesktop.org/images/2/20/Tango-feet.png) is an example set of icons that would be perfect (size/style) if it included the actual icons I need. In fact I'll probably use some of those icons anyway, such as the cut, paste and save icons. I also might use the 'play' and 'record' buttons for start and create breakpoint respectively.

**I'm especially looking for** step/run-to-cursor icons. Preferred icon size: 22x22px.

---

**EDIT:** What about the Netbeans icons? They're the perfect size and look very nice, but I can't seem to find any information about whether or not I'm allowed to use them. I realize netbeans is opensource, but I can't figure out if I can take the icons.

**EDIT:** It turns out that using NetBeans icons is [fine](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUseOfImagesOtherPrograms), so I'm going with that. Thanks everyone!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/153840/where-can-i-find-free-icons-closed which doesn't mean I think your question a) belongs on SU b) should be closed. The question was just in my short term cache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use some of the icons from [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) = they are available under [the same licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Public_License) as the rest of Eclipse. I had a quick look at my local install of Eclipse and lots of the icons are in subfolders under `configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles` so you could search through the .gifs under there.

Comment: Thanks - this was the idea that prompted me to look at other ide's, which led to netbeans. So here's the bounty!

Answer (score 8):

A set of icons with a liberal license can be found at http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/. They're not IDE specific, but there are lots of them, only 16x16 though.

Comment: IIRC the Silk set includes debugger icons.

Comment: It doesn't have any step icons, but I like the application_ icons, which I'll probably use for dissassembly and other application related options in some of the menus.

Answer (score 6):

About using [Standard Microsoft Icons](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2006/06/06/618797.aspx).

The vast majority of developers out there don't know that Visual Studio comes with an Image Library. So here goes two links that highlight it:

[About using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Image Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/29/tips-and-tricks-visual-studio-2010-image-library.aspx).

[About using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035.aspx).

Comment: This is fantastic. However currently I'm using the 2010 release candidate visual studio. I'll be getting an actual license eventually, but any idea if I can still use the icons? Edit: The RC didn't come with many icons, so it looks like I'm out of luck here.

Comment: Yes. The best part is: you can use these icons and images in your actual application, not just for mockups!

Comment: I think I'll probably take the continue, stop, pause, etc icons from this. They are all very nice and suit my needs nicely. I might also take some others, such as copy/paste, save, load etc.. However it doesn't look like any of the step icons are included (step-over, etc). Am I just not seeing them? Like I said there aren't as many icons as mentioned in those links, which could be because it's an RC version.

Comment: Probably the step icons are not included...

Answer (score 5):

how about http://sekkyumu.deviantart.com/art/Developpers-Icons-63052312

"You are free to use these icons on personal and/or commercial projects without any attribution or credit. "

[image]
<sub>(source: [deviantart.net](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs27/i/2008/035/5/d/Developpers_Icons_by_Sekkyumu.png))</sub>

**EDIT**

also look at http://lokheed.deviantart.com/art/gperfection-sup2-Icon-Set-18530981

AND

[Fugue Icons](https://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/)

[Preview(Big)](https://web.archive.org/web/20121003203303/http://fugue-icons-src.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/all-preview.png)

---

And here (BUT ITS $74.5) ->

http://www.awicons.com/stock-icons/xp-artistic-icons/

Step-over 
[image]

Compile
[image: Compile]

Step-into
[image]

Run to cursor
[image]

Comment: These are great! I'll probably use the play, pause, and stop buttons from this set. Sadly however, there's no step/run-to icons in this set.

Comment: Updated post with 2 more packs that may interest you

Comment: That $75 pack is incredibely tempting... I may indeed go with that if nothing else comes up!

Answer (score 3):

The [Crystal icons](http://everaldo.com/crystal/) are pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

this is a nice icon set: http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/
can find just about anything else here: http://www.iconfinder.com/

Comment: lol: http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=programming

Answer (score 1):

The [Humanity](https://launchpad.net/humanity) icons from Ubuntu are awesome.

100% SVG, license GPLv2.